# how do I get only text field data from django modelform for email submission?

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, email

how do I get only the text field data from a django modelform for email submission?  Ive tried a lot of variations in the view, cleaned_data.get() def clean(self): methods etc.  Not sure why this is so hard.

```
# models.py - service model
class Service(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    service_type = models.ManyToManyField('ServiceType')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Service Order for: {user}".format(user=self.user)


class ServiceType(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

# forms.py
class NewServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    accept_tos = forms.BooleanField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user', 'created_at',)

# views.py
@login_required
def newservice(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewServiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            service = form.save()

# SEND EMAIL - send copy of project/service modelform data to user and site owner

            name = request.user.first_name+request.user.last_name
            username = request.user.username
            subject = 'New Service Order'
            from_email = request.user.email
            service_data = form.cleaned_data
            message = ''' From:    {}    {}    {}
            \n {}
            \n {}
            '''.format(name, from_email, username, subject, service_data)
            recipients = ['mytestemail@gmail.com', request.user.email]
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipients)
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
# END EMAIL
            messages.warning(request, 'Success! Your service order has been submitted.')
            return redirect('projects')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid submission, check and try again.')
    else:
        form = NewServiceForm()

    return render(request, 'dashboard/newservice.html', {'form': form})

# newservice.html

<form method="post" id="newprojectform">        
            {% csrf_token %}

         Service Type <br> {{ form.service_type }} <br><br>
                  {{ form.accept_tos }} <br><br>
       Description  {{ form.description }} <br><br>
       <button class="btn btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button> 
                </div>
</form>
```

Im getting wrong output sent to my email inbox below: I just want text output of choices, and description sent to my email inbox (and not boolean=True), ie  'Edit Content Add Content  Test Description goes here'

```
 {'service_type': <QuerySet [<ServiceType: Edit Content>, <ServiceType: Add Content>, 'accept_tos': True, 'description': 'Test Description goes here'}
```

Comment: please post the `template` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lots of issues with m2m form field data retrieval I pulled data from the created model using project = form.save()  object.  much strife, but somewhat easier solution.